# roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden even added in apiGroups

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-helm

I'm running kubernetes v1.11.5 and I'm installing helm with a tiller deployment for each namespace. 
Let's focus on a single namespace. This is the tiller service account configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: marketplace-int
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager
  namespace: marketplace-int
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - extensions
  - apps
  - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  - roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  - authorization.k8s.io
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-binding
  namespace: marketplace-int
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: marketplace-int
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: tiller-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

When I try to deploy a chart I get this error:

```
Error: release citest failed: roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "marketplace-int-role-ns-admin" is forbidden: 
attempt to grant extra privileges: 
[{[*] [*] [*] [] []}] user=&{system:serviceaccount:marketplace-int:tiller 5c6af739-1023-11e9-a245-0ab514dfdff4 
[system:serviceaccounts system:serviceaccounts:marketplace-int system:authenticated] map[]} 
ownerrules=[{[create] [authorization.k8s.io] [selfsubjectaccessreviews selfsubjectrulesreviews] [] []} 
{[get] [] [] [] [/api /api/* /apis /apis/* /healthz /openapi /openapi/* /swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1 /swagger.json /swaggerapi /swaggerapi/* /version /version/]} 
{[*] [ extensions apps rbac.authorization.k8s.io roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io authorization.k8s.io] [*] [] []}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

The error comes when trying to create rbac config for that namespace (with tiller sa):

```
# Source: marketplace/templates/role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    app: citest
    chart: marketplace-0.1.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: citest
    namespace: marketplace-int
  name: marketplace-int-role-ns-admin
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]
```

The error message clearly says that the tiller service account doesn't have permission for `roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io` but that permission is granted as showed previously.

```
$kubectl describe role tiller-manager
Name:         tiller-manager
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"tiller-manager","namespace":"marketplace-i...
PolicyRule:
  Resources                          Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                          -----------------  --------------  -----
  *                                  []                 []              [*]
  *.apps                             []                 []              [*]
  *.authorization.k8s.io             []                 []              [*]
  *.extensions                       []                 []              [*]
  *.rbac.authorization.k8s.io        []                 []              [*]
  *.roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io  []                 []              [*]
```

Honestly, I don't fully understand the error message to check if the `ownerrules` are fine and I'm trying to find out what does it means this kind of messages that seems to be related with the role description: `{[*] [*] [*] [] []}`

Any clue about what permissions I am missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is due to permission escalation prevention in RBAC. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#privilege-escalation-prevention-and-bootstrapping for details.

Permission to create a role object is necessary, but not sufficient.

A user can only create/update a role if at least one of the following things is true:

1. they already have all the permissions contained in the role, at the same scope as the object being modified (cluster-wide for a ClusterRole, within the same namespace or cluster-wide for a Role). In your case, that would mean the user attempting to create the role must already have `apiGroups=*, resources=*, verbs=*` permissions within the namespace where it is attempting to create the role. You can grant this by granting the cluster-admin clusterrole to the serviceaccount within that namespace with a rolebinding.
2. they are given explicit permission to perform the "escalate" verb on the roles or clusterroles resource in the rbac.authorization.k8s.io API group (Kubernetes 1.12 and newer)

Comment: with kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-clusteradmin-mkp-int --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=marketplace-int:tiller works fine. If I have three tiller deployments, all of them will have permissions to create anything at  cluster level? If there is any error configuring CI, that could cause to use tiller inside namespace 1 to deploy into namespace2?

Comment: You can easily test that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to give cluster-admin permission to tiller SA.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: marketplace-int
```

Once you assign cluster-admin role to tiller SA, you should be able to create the role.

Comment: But I don’t want to give cluster level permissions. That’s the reason I’m creating a tiller per namespace. Let’s forget tiller. With a SA with the permissions listed in my question I can’t create that role for an authorized namespace. Is that correct?

Comment: Solved my problems successfully, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create roles within that same namespace. I tried this myself, meaning creating a role using the same role that you described in your question and I was able to do it successfully (I changed my namespace to test), so I don't think it's related to your role definition but how tiller is using that specific service account to create new things.

```
# With an cluster-admin cluster role
$ echo '---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: test
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager
  namespace: test
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - extensions
  - apps
  - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  - roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  - authorization.k8s.io
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-binding
  namespace: test
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: test
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: tiller-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Then:

```
$ kubectl -n test describe secret tiller-token-xxxxx
Name:         tiller-token-xxxx
Namespace:    test
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: tiller

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  4 bytes
token:      <my-token>
```

Then:

```
$ mv ~/.kube ~/.kube.tmp
$ echo 'apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    app: citest
    chart: marketplace-0.1.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: citest
  namespace: test
  name: marketplace-int-role-ns-admin
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]' | kubectl -n test --token <your-token> --server <your-kubeapiserver> apply -f - 
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/marketplace-int-role-ns-admin created
```